# random delay timer in PHP

Tags: php, random, timer

I want to put a php daemon to sleep (with System_Daemon::iterate())
so it runs max 20 times randomly spread over an hour. maybe a min distance would be smart so it doesn't run 20 times in the first half hour and 0 times in the second half.

i'm kinda stuck here and don't know how to start with this one, any help is very apreciated!

Comment: Always makes me wonder why anyone would do that.

Comment: There is a need to do this sort of thing when you are running large farms of servers and you do not want the exact same scheduled maintenance to happen on all hosts at once, or even on the exact same frequency.  This is a good question for people in that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i came up with one possible solution, i didnt try it out yet, so it main contain syntax or logic errors. because it is running as a daemon there is a never ending loop around it.

```
// 3600 seconds or one hour
$timeframe=3600;
// run max 20 times in $timeframe
$runtimes=20;
// minimum delay between two executions
$mindelay=60;
// maxium delay between two executions
$maxdelay=240;

if ($cnt % $runtimes != 0) {
    $delay = rand($mindelay,$maxdelay);    
    System_Daemon::iterate($delay);    
    $sum += $delay;
    $cnt++;
} else {
    //final delay till the $timeframe
    if ($sum < $timeframe) {
        System_Daemon::iterate($timeframe - $sum); 
    }  
    $sum=0;
}
```

its not perfect and u waste some time but i guess its going to fullfill the job.
any comments?

Answer (score 3):

You may use cron jobs, to set the script to run ever so often.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

---

... Crontab:

```
0 9 * * * /path/to/bashscript
```

and in /path/to/bashscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
maxdelay=$((1*60))  # every hour, converted to minutes
for ((i=1; i<=20; i++)); do
    delay=$(($RANDOM%maxdelay)) # pick an independent random delay, 20 times
    (sleep $((delay*60)); /path/to/phpscript.php) & # background a subshell, then run the php script
done
```

Comment: Do you any reference to how to make a cron job run at random intervals, because I am not aware of such functionality.

Comment: Ok in that case cron is not doing the randomizing, but rather the long-running bash script is.  I will +1 the Answer as I think the same approach used in the bash script could be used by the original poster in PHP.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i also thought about crons, but didn't see any possibility to realize it.
but this solution also has some flaws like its not guaranteed that it wont run at the same time.