# how to run tasks/function with some random delay in php

Tags: php

I need to run a task/function with some random delay between 2-20 seconds. How can I do so in PHP? I've tried looking at rabbit mq for publisher and consumer and didn't find a way to have rabbit mq consumer to do it randomly

Comment: You want this to happen in the background I assume. Is kicking off a background process using one of PHP's shell exec methods an option?

Comment: Yea, I wanted to schedule it inside a queue, and yes its a background process

Comment: Then the answer will be specific to the queue you want to use. Different queueing systems have ways of indicating when a queued job should run, this isn't a PHP issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [random delay timer in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991055/random-delay-timer-in-php)